# Safety, security and reliability. What is the difference?

Tags: security, reliability

Safety, security and reliability. What is the difference? Please short answers ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**security** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security

**reliability** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_(engineering)

hope it helps

Comment: I want basic information about them. as comparison type...